# Using a foreach loop to get create variables from $_POST security issues?

Tags: php, security, post

In the past I have used the following to create variables from a posted form.

```
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v)
{
    $$k = $v;
}
```

What are the security risks associates with using this method?

im trying some test atm. how about this version where it removes anything that is not a letter or number before making the variable?

```
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v)
{
    $k = preg_replace("/[^[:alnum:]]/","",$k);
    $$k=$v;
}
```

Comment: `extract($_POST)` will also do that.

Comment: Never heard of extract just started reading it. according to the php page its preventing invalid variables and overwriting variables. by default php replaces invalid characters in the post with _ . i.e a field named foo.x will become foo_x after it has been posted. I'm not worried about variables being over written but this will be helpful for future projects. thanks

Comment: I should also note the only time I've found `extract()` useful is when creating a `View` type controller for unpacking vars into an included view inside of an output buffer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An attacker can inject a POST variable called `_SESSION` and by that write data in your session so you can't trust your session anymore.

Comment: This still lets the bad person overwrite arbitrary variables. Why would you need such a thing? Fetch the data you need from the array.

Comment: I made a form with invalid field names including _SESSION _SESSION[name] $_SESSION $_SESSION[name] and so far have been unable to create a session variable with my second example

Comment: @jphannes because it is much faster then writing out 1 line of code per a posted variable. some cases I've had 50+ fields that where posted in a form. as for overwriting variables I can use extract (thanks alex).

Comment: @yamiko The point is, why `extract` the variables in the first place? Just work with `$_POST['foo']`, period.

Comment: you cant use $_POST['foo'] in all the situations you can use $foo

Comment: @yamiko I'd really like to see a concrete proof for that claim. I have never had any problems working with arrays in PHP.

Comment: @deceze: I like to always keep the `$_POST` *as is*. Perhaps that is what the OP meant?

Comment: @alex Then `$post = $_POST` is a fine solution. Extracting all the contents into individual variables usually only makes your life *harder*.